# How to add a slideshow to a custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, branding

i have created a custom master page( converted an html page to master page) .
I want to add a slideshow to the page,but i am not able to make the picture library snippet to work. I have tried with the image web part snippet but cant seem to be able to resize the pictures only the webpart in overall is being resized

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure about the master page and such, but you if you are using SharePoint 2013 or later you can add the **Content Search** web part or the **Pictures** web part to any web page – site page or web part page - and display an image slideshow.  Large images are cropped to fit and display nicely.

When editing a web page the **Content Search** web part is usually in the **Content Rollup** category and the **Pictures** web part is usually in the **Search-Driven Content** category.

1. Edit a web page.
2. Add the one of the two web parts to the page.
3. Edit the web part.
4. In web part settings, in the **Search Criteria** section click **Change Query**, then in the **Restrict by app** drop down select **Specify a URL**  and enter your picture library’s URL.  Click **Ok**.
5. In web part settings, in the **Display Templates** section, in the **Control** drop down select **Slideshow**, and in the **Item** drop down select **Large Picture**.

Comment: please have a look at the image i have added i am not able to increase the image to fit the entire column.Note  increasing the size of the web part doesnt increase the image size,.

Comment: The image size in your screenshot is the default sizing.  To modify that I believe you'd have to create a new item display template.

Comment: how exactly do i create a new template

Comment: There are countless bogs that can walk you through creating a display template.  I suggest you read through a few a couple times before you crack any HTML files open.  I also suggest you present your customer with the available implementation options and let them decide.  I use a template that provides a visual resource to share with stakeholders when their input is required to select the best implementation option before mockup-ups or site content is created.  It is available at https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/planning-for-site-customizations-and-solutions/.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,just need to change the size accordingly :https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-slider-display-template